# Foreign Key issues in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

I am having this issue where I'm only able to get the error message. I have some tables where student id is the foreign key, however even thou the id number is not any of the tables it still gives the message "You cannot delete this Student" but won't pass there if it can be deleted

```
public function findBystudentid($studentid)
    {


     $record= $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:record')->findBy(['studentid' => $studentid]);
            $lecture = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:lecture')->findBy(['studentid' => $studentid]);
            $faculty = $this->getEntityManager()->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:faculty')->findBy(['studentid' => $studentid]);
            if ($record||$lecture||$faculty){
                        return true;
                    } else {
                        return false;
                    }
}

public function deleteAction(Request $request, $studentid)
    {
        $form = $this->createDeleteForm($studentid);
        $form->handleRequest($request);

        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $deletable = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Student')->findBystudentid($studentid);

            if ($deletable) {
                $this->addFlash('error','ERROR! You cannot delete this Student' );
            } 
            else 
                {

                $em->remove($deletable);
                $em->flush();
                $this->addFlash('error','Student Deleted');
                }
            return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('Student'));

    }
```

Comment: $delete != $deletable

Comment: it is actually deletable not delete.

Comment: Your `$deletable` is of `bool` type. Why? As such, you won't be able to `$em->remove()` it

Comment: what be returned in the repository?

Comment: @JovanPerovic, could you suggest an answer please.

Comment: I think the real solution would be to have "findbystudentid" return the student entity, and then use a [voter](https://symfony.com/doc/current/security/voters.html) to decide if you can delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, your naming is a bit off. You need to fix it as it tends to be a bit confusing. With that in mind, I suggest you do it like this:

**<kbd>1. Controller method to check if student is deletable:</kbd>**

```
private function isStudentDeletable($studentid)
{
    $em = $this->getEntityManager();

    $record= $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:record')->findBy(['studentid' => $studentid]);
    if ( $record ){
        return false;
    }

    $lecture = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:lecture')->findBy(['studentid' => $studentid]);

    if ( $lecture ){
        return false;
    }

    $faculty = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:faculty')->findBy(['studentid' => $studentid]);

    if ( $faculty ){
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

**<kbd>2. Controller's action to invoke the above</kbd>**

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $studentid)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($studentid);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $deletable = $this->isStudentDeletable($studentid);

    if (!$deletable) {
        $this->addFlash('error','ERROR! You cannot delete this Student' );
    } 
    else 
    {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $student = $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Student')->find($studentid)
        $em->remove($student);
        $em->flush();
        $this->addFlash('error','Student Deleted');
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('Student'));
}
```

Hope this help and clarifies a bit.

Comment: Is there a remote chance that your student is being used elsewhere?

Comment: Can you share what was the issue? Others here at SO could learn from your mistake :)

Comment: it was a mistake on my part. left off the ! (!$deletable)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are calling `findBystudentid` wrong because `findBystudentid` is not in the Entity.

Here is the updated version

```
public function deleteAction(Request $request, $studentid)
{
    $form = $this->createDeleteForm($studentid);
    $form->handleRequest($request);

    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $deletable = $this->findBystudentid($studentid);

    if ($deletable) {
      $this->addFlash('error','ERROR! You cannot delete this Student' );
    } else {
      $em->getRepository('AcmeDemoBundle:Student')->findBy(['studentid' => $studentid])
      $em->remove($deletable);
      $em->flush();
      $this->addFlash('error','Student Deleted');
    }

    return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl('Student'));
}
```

Also `findBystudentid` should be a private function

```
private function findByStudentId() ...
```

Comment: Yes, @user742736 is right. By the looks of it, `findBystudentid` belongs to your `Controller` class and not to your repository...

Comment: I'm just trying to find if the student id is present in the tables and then return true or false

Comment: how would that look in the controller